# Select the row number X in SQLITE when order by desc

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm using SQLITE (so no row_number)

Here is my database call : tableau

```
ID | Nom  | Score
---|------|------
1  | Clem | 50
2  | Caro | 60
3  | Flo  | 55
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM tableau ORDER BY Score DESC
```

And here is what I get:

```
ID | Nom  | Score
---|------|------
2  | Caro | 60
3  | Flo  | 55
1  | Clem | 50
```

But I would like to get the "Nom" value at 2nd row after its sorted in descending order

I thought using :

```
SELECT Nom FROM tableau WHERE rowid = 2 ORDER BY Score DESC
```

But the result is "Caro" (Expected Result : "Flo")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't support window functions or variables, the two methods you would use in other databases.  The best way to handle this is often at the application layer

You can get the *rank* of a row and then use that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select 1 + count(*)
              from tableau t2
              where t2.score > t.score
             ) as rnk
      from tableau t
     ) t
where rnk = 2;
```

Note that this gives tied scores the same rank.

I should note that you can also phrase this as:

```
select t.*
from tableau t
where 2 = (select 1 + count(*)
           from tableau t2
           where t2.score > t.score
          );
```

EDIT:

If you want a stable sort, you have to include it in the logic:

```
select t.*
from tableau t
where 2 = (select 1 + count(*)
           from tableau t2
           where t2.score > t.score or
                 (t2.score = t.score and t2.name < t.name)
          );
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it works!! thank you! What does mean "t.*" ? and "tableau t" ....what is the t?

Comment: As you said, if 2 scores are equals... there is a problem, how can I add, If 2 scores are equals then sort by name ?

Comment: Thank you so much....3 hours i was on this!!!!! Thank you!!!!!! And i understand now!